# losing principal with custom AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter and custom AuthenticationProvider

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I'm (still) trying to use a custom AuthenticationProvider in Grails 2.5.x. I need to pick up form data, so I wrote a PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter to do that and write the principal.

Both of these classes are getting called, so I at least have some of the bean configuration correct. The problem is that the information isn't being stored from the filter, so the AuthenticationProvider doesn't have data to authenticate. I'll show relevant details from the classes and the log entries that go along with it.

preauth filter:

```
class PreAuthenticationRequestParametersFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {
    protected Map xmlMap

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (! request.getParameter('SAMLResponse')) {
            // no need to process if we don't have a SAML response.
            // Remember this will get called on pretty much every request.
            return null
        }
        String samlResponseXml = request.getParameter('SAMLResponse')
        log.warn("xmlfoo: ${samlResponseXml?.length()} and sch: ${SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication}")
        if (! samlResponseXml) return null

        xmlMap = decodeXml(samlResponseXml)
        log.warn("principal: ${xmlMap.userDetails}")

        return xmlMap.userDetails
    }

    // (not showing decodeXml, shouldn't be necessary)
```

SAMLAuth:

```
class SAMLAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
@Override
    Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        log.warn("hello from samlauthprovider, auth: ${authentication}")
        String name = authentication.name
        log.warn("name: ${name}")

        String principal = authentication.principal
        log.warn("principal: ${principal}")

        if (name == '' || principal == '') return null // authentication

        // code continues, but the failure has already occurred, these are blank in the log below
```

log:

```
WARN  myapp.PreAuthenticationRequestParametersFilter  - user email: bob@domain.com with user User(id: 4, username: bob, firstName: bob, lastName: b, email: bob@domain.com, enabled: true, accountExpired: false, accountLocked: false, passwordExpired: false)
WARN  myapp.PreAuthenticationRequestParametersFilter  - issuer: https://saml.domain.com/adfs/services/trust with auth 1  
WARN  myapp.PreAuthenticationRequestParametersFilter  - principal: myapp.MyAppUserDetails@8ee96c84: Username: bob@domain.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER 
WARN  security.SAMLAuthenticationProvider  - hello from samlauthprovider,
auth: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@b37b: Principal: ; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 172.31.2.90; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities
WARN  security.SAMLAuthenticationProvider  - name:
WARN  security.SAMLAuthenticationProvider  - principal:                   
// next logs are in my "login failed" code, which we shouldn't reach in this case
```

I'm well aware there's a spring-security-saml class. I'm not using it for reasons that are tangental to this question.

**edit** with more logging, I'm seeing the flow is PreAuthenticated, then my success handler, then my SAMLAuthenticationProvider. Things seem to get lost after the success handler. That's really odd for several reasons- why is the success handler getting called before the AuthenticationProvider?